# FormAuthentication with WebAPI using Breeze

Tags: breeze

I am protecting WebAPI using forms Authentication, that is using Breezecontroller
When i try to call WebAPi method i am getting back the following error.

status:404
statusText: "Not Found"
message:"MetaData query failed for:'';, No Http resource was found tha matches...

My question is why am i not getting back "UnAuthorized error(401)" ?
metadata is decorated with  [Authorize] as well.

Seems like FormsAuthentication's redirect is giving problem.
It is redirecting to Login(has AllowAnonymous) WebApi method and reports it cannot find, eventhough i have. Also i am applying the Authrozie to the methods instead of controller.  the exact error is

```
  {"$id":"1","$type":"System.Web.Http.HttpError,System.Web.Http","Message":"NoHTTPresourcewasfoundthatmatchestherequestURI'http://localhost:40678/api/Country/Login?ReturnUrl=/api/Country/Metadata'.","MessageDetail":"Noactionwasfoundonthecontroller'Country'thatmatchestherequest."}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried and working fine. I'm betting you have a mistake in your URL.

Here is the prelim to my controller:

```
[Authorize]
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeTodoController : ApiController
{
    private readonly BreezeTodoContext _context;

    public BreezeTodoController() {
        _context = new BreezeTodoContext(User);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata() {
        return _context.Metadata();
    }
    // ... more
```

I hit it with this URL

```
http://localhost:32377/api/breezetodox/metadata
```

And I get back the 401

```
Request URL:http://localhost:32377/api/breezetodo/metadata
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

But if I make a mistake in the URL (see 'x' after breezetodo)

```
Request URL:http://localhost:32377/api/breezetodox/metadata
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

Same thing if my action name doesn't match (see 'x' after metadata):

```
Request URL:http://localhost:32377/api/breezetodo/metadatax
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

**In other words, HTTP can't report that a resource is unauthorized if it can't find that resource in the first place.**

Comment: Seems like FormsAuthentication's redirect is giving problem.

Comment: Ward, i am still getting 404, and the reason being the FormsAuthentication is redirecting to login URL, after finding that the user is not authorized. in your example are you using FormsAuthentication, i was able to improve that by providing method signature in the loginURL and now it runs the Authentication method and i get UserNot Found. So i was wondering is there a better way to do configure FormsAuthentication with WebAPI ?

Comment: I haven't spent the time with this that I should (and will). For my example here I hijacked the [MVC 4 SPA Template](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application) sample which has an login and registration UI to go with the Todo app

Comment: I accepted the answer, based on that we have installed ASP.NET Fall 2012 Update BUILD. otherwise the FormsAuthentication's redirect is giving problem. i did find solution to suppress redirect, but think that updating to ASP.NET Fall 2012 Update fixes that problem

Answer (score 0):

when tagging the BreezeController with [Authorize] and then trying to retrieve the Breeze Metadata directly with this link:

```
Request URL:http://localhost/breeze/breeze/metadata
```

redirects to:

```
http://localhost/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fbreeze%2Fbreeze%2Fmetadata with a 404
```

Without the [Authorize] the access to the Breeze metadata with the same link works fine.